# Informatica Developer 10.5.2.1 - To read multiple part parquet files from Azure DataLake Storage Gen2

Tags: informatica, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have one folder in ADLS Gen2 which has more than one part parquet files. I need to read all these parquet files in one shot with Informatica Developer and i need to write all of them into another folder in ADLS Gen2.

Do you have any suggestion?

Thank you
Ozge

1- I took only last day's data from one folder under ADLS Gen2 which has only 1 file for each day. (with using parameterization) Since i run this mapping with Databricks, at the end i have multiple part parquet files.
2- As a 2.step i need to read these all part parquet files. If i use dataobject that i created at 1.step, i thought it will read all files. But it does not.